# Path Problem for CSS. Noob

Tags: php, zend-framework

Css path is not working properly. Can someone help me how to fix this. I am new to Zend.

main.css is at root in public/css folder. Following this link for learning http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.quick-start.html

**PROBLEM:**

*I am defining headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/main.css') ?>
in Layout see below. But this is not generating correct path and thus not applying style.I want to generate link with headlink() function. main.css should be rendered from public/css folder at the root*

Narrow down problem. This **is working** if I remove / before css like. **Why is that?**

```
<?= $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/main.css') ?>
```

Folder Structure
[image]

Below is index.php

```
<?php
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'));
define('APPLICATION_PATH', BASE_PATH . '/application');

// Include path
set_include_path(
    BASE_PATH . '/library'
);


// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV',
              (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')
                                         : 'production'));

// Zend_Application
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap();
$application->run();
```

Comment: Please define what exactly is "not working properly".

Comment: @deceze , edited my question and added Problem. See at the top of question. I want to use headLink() function not <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> .

Comment: What is being output when you view the source of the page?

Comment: @tim-fountain , Edited my question. Please read

Comment: You've still not provided enough to allow us to answer your question. When you say it is "not working properly", do you mean the `<link>` element is not being output? If it is, is it being output with a path other than the one you are supplying? Does the stylesheet work if you view it directly in the browser - http://localhost/css/main.css ?

Answer (score 0):

you're working in your view i guess?

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

something like this?

Comment: , edited my question and added Problem. See at the top of question. I want to use headLink() function not <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Answer (score 0):

1) You are not outputting the css file at the layout. I mean to say, you will have to use an echo while appending the last css.

```
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/global.css');
echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/main.css'); ?>
```

2) You will have to use two dots(..) before the url of the css file get the css while working in an action controllers view file. like this:

```
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('../css/global.css');
echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('../css/main.css'); ?>
```

Comment: try to open the css file directly first and check if the url u r giving is targeting the css or not.

For ex put in ur address bar, // http://UR_URL/css/main.css

Comment: I think initially the zend is taking your url as ur_url/ so when you wrote '/css/main.css' the complete path is generated like ur_url//css/main.css. Notice the doubled '/'. What ever, your problem is solved then enjoy... :)

Comment: Same here, I just got command on it. the examples given in it's documentation never works, the online tutorial is too bad.